# Issues enabling my nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 15.04, bumblebee, gpu-driver

I'm trying to enable my nvidia driver and it appears in additional drivers and I have selected it there but it seem to be actually using it. I heard that sometimes the nouveau driver will always have a higher precedence so I tried using bumblebee but haven't had much success with it. Thanks for any help!

Here's what lshw -c video displays -

```
    *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ec000000-ecffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:ed000000-ed07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:ed400000-ed7fffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

I tried using optirun but get this error:

```
[23659.826406] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[23659.826449] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try Xorg-Edgers ppa for the drivers. From there you would get the latest drivers.

### Blacklist Nouveau drivers

First you should blacklist Nouveau drivers. You can do it by running

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nouveau.conf
```

(You can use any other text editor as well, if you don't like nano)

And then you add these lines to that file

```
blacklist nouveau
blacklist lbm-nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
alias nouveau off
alias lbm-nouveau off
```

### Install Nvidia drivers

First you should remove all previous Nvidia drivers by running

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
```

Then you can add xorg-edgers ppa

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-349
```

(You can change the `nvidia-349` to what ever is the latest. **Currently** 349.16 is the latest, so `nvidia-349` is the way to go. Or if you want older drivers.)

When you want to update your drivers, just run

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-xxx
```

Xorg Edgers also provide Bumblebee, but i don't have any experience about Bumblebee. Someone can edit this post with info about it.

Comment: I tried blacklisting nouveau and the driver appears to be enabled in the additional drivers tab of the system settings but it but it doesn't to be using the driver.